# Linking Value from Javascript to .cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an asp list item with a text box. I need to pass the text box value to my .aspx.cs file.This is the code.  I created the hidden field control, but this control is not taking the javascript variable value in server side code. Please help.

```
 <asp:ListItem Value=">1000"> <input type="text"  id="tbGreater"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"><br/> </asp:ListItem>`
```

Comment: where is hidden field? How are you accessing it's value?

Comment: `<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>` This is after the list ends. ' function SetHdnField() {
                var x = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
                x.value = document.getElementById("tbGreater").value;
                
            }'  I am calling this  function on Click of a button

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientID` to access server control in javascript. Javascript function should be

```
function SetHdnField() { 
    document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById("tbGreater").value; 
}
```

Reaon is `HiddenField1` is a server side control and it's id is changed during rendering.

Comment: I hope it doesnt affect my control. Not able to access it in Code behind now. :(

Comment: Hey.. Sorry.. It just worked.. Had to add OnClientClick and not OnClick event. Thanks